# GLSL stops rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I want to write a signed distance interpretation. For that I am creating a voxelgrid 100*100*100 for example (the size will increase if it is working).
Now my plans are to load a point cloud into a 1d texture:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, _texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, pc->pc.size(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &pc->pc.front());

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
```

'pc' is just a class which holds a vector of structure Point, which has only floats x,y,z,w.

Than I want to render the hole 100x100x100 grid, so each voxel and iterate trough all points of that texture, calculate the distance to my current voxel and store that distance in a new texture (1000x1000). For the moment this texture I am creating holds only color valuables which stores the distance in the red and green component and blue is set to 1.0.
So I can see the result on screen.

My problem is now, that when I have about 500 000 points in my point cloud, It seems to stop rendering after a few voxels(less than 50 000). My guess is that if it takes to long, it stops and just trow out the buffer that it has. 
I don't know if that can be the case but if it is, is there something I can do against it, or maybe something I can do to make this procedure better/faster.

My second guess is, that there is something I don't consider with the 1D Texture. But is there a better way to pass in a high amount of data? Because I will surely need a few hundred thousand points data.

I don't know if it helps if I show the full fragment shader, so I will only show some parts, which I think is important for that problem:

Distance calculation and iteration through all points:

```
for(int i = 0; i < points; ++i){
        vec4 texInfo = texture(textureImg, getTextCoord(i));
        vec4 pos = position;
        pos.z /= rows*rows;
        vec4 distVector = texInfo-pos;
        float dist = sqrt(distVector.x*distVector.x + distVector.y*distVector.y + distVector.z*distVector.z);
        if(dist < minDist){
            minDist = dist;
        }
    }
```

Function getTexCoord:

```
float getTextCoord(float a)
{
    return (a * 2.0f + 1.0f) / (2.0f * points);
}
```

*Edit:

```
vec4 newPos = vec4(makeCoord(position.x+Col())-1,
                   makeCoord(position.y+Row())-1,
                   0,
                   1.0);

float makeCoord(float a){
return (a/rows)*2;
}

int Col(){
float a = mod(position.z,rows);
return int(a);
}

int Row()
{
    float a = position.z/rows;
    return int(a);
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? On Windows it could be that the WDDM forces your app out (although it should look more as a driver restore than shader exit)

Comment: OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5

Comment: Then it cannot be it. Are you sure your volume isn't being culled?

Comment: I don't think so, it is working correctly if I am using only a small amount of points in my point cloud, like 1000 but if I use 10000 It makes problems.

Comment: I edit the calculation for the position.

Comment: And I have to explain here, that for the calculation in Row and Col the values are integers (0 to 99). I actually divide them by the grid size to calculate the distance, so I have a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: How long does it run until it stops? Most systems kill off GPU jobs that don't finish within a few seconds.

Comment: This is never going to work in real-time unless you do something to reduce the amount of work per-fragment. Right now I guarantee you what is happening is that your fragment is taking too long, it triggers a watchdog timer and the OpenGL context is reset by the driver. There are robustness extensions to avoid killing lengthy shader executions but that's only a band-aid. Consider using a geometry shader or something to split this job across multiple simple invocations and merge the results at the end. I don't really understand what you're trying to do here to be any more specific than that.

Comment: My goal is a point cloud fusion to reconstruct a model/scene out of depth images. I read that it is been made with a signed distance function. Thats why I am testing to make a signed distance representation to see what kind of problems I could get and how I would make it. To reduce the amount of work per fragment I am thinking of storing the points in a kd tree, so I have fast access to the nearest neighbors. But I think that such a signed distance representation is made differenty than I did it. That's why I am testing how I would do that bevor I go deeper in to optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You absolutely shouldn`t be looping through all of your points in a fragment shader, as it gets calculated N times per frame (where N equals the number of pixels), which effectively gives you O(N<sup>2</sup>) computational complexity.
2. All textures have limits on how much data they can hold per dimension. Two most important values here are GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE and GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE. As stated in [official docs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory),

   > Texture sizes have a limit based on the GL implementation. For 1D and 2D textures (and any texture types that use similar dimensionality, like cubemaps) the max size of either dimension is GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE. For array textures, the maximum array length is GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS. For 3D textures, no dimension can be greater than GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE in size.
   >
   > Within these limits, the size of a texture can be any value. It is advised however, that you stick to powers-of-two for texture sizes, unless you have a significant need to use arbitrary sizes.

   The most typical values are listed [here](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) and [here](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE).
3. If you really have to use large data amounts inside your frag shader, consider a 2D or 3D texture with known power-of-2 dimensions and GL_NEAREST / GL_REPEAT coordinates. This will enable you to compute 2D texture coords just by multiplying the source offset by a precomputed 1/width value (Y coord; the remainder is by definition smaller than 1 texel and can be safely ignored in the presence of GL_NEAREST) and using it as-is for X coord (GL_REPEAT guarantees that only the remainder gets used). Personally I implemented this approach when I needed to pass 128 MB of data to a GLSL 1.20 shader.
4. If you are targeting a recent enough OpenGL (≥ 3.0), you also can use [buffer textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture).
5. And the last, but not the least. You cannot pass integer-precision values greater than 2<sup>24</sup> through standard IEEE floats.